# Scale the vimeo video according to the container size and remove the black bars

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, vimeo

I would like to remove black bars that appears in vimeo video that has been embedded. I am sharing the link of the code. [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jen825gh/)

```
<div class="embed-container">
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/86019637?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

`iframe{
width:570px;
height:250px;
}`

There are 2 black bar left and right. We would like to remove the black bars. Could you please help what could be done to remove it? We are supposed to maintain the aspect ratio. Please go easy on me, I am not a technical guy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `height` and `width` `vh` like

```
.embed-container {
  width: 570px;
  height: 250px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

videos has an aspect ratio and it will mainten that's why video looks like, when you do it full screen the bars will vanish.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for answering. We are able to remove the vertical black bars with this solution but we are getting horizontal black bars. Here is the link: [Updated Code JSFiddle]https://jsfiddle.net/jen825gh/3/